# How to share primary navigation of main site with subsites usining switch_to_blog

Tags: multisite, navigation

I have managed to switch the primiary navigation menu of my subsites to show the main site primary navigation.

However, it renders above the site-header instead of in the menu location dictated in the code.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    function wp_multisite_nav_menu() {
    global $blog_id;
}
    if ( ! is_multisite() || 2 == $blog_id ) {

    switch_to_blog( 1 );

    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 2,
        'fallback_cb'       => false,
        'menu_class'        => 'genesis-nav-menu',
        'theme_location'    => 'Primary Navigation Menu',

    )); 

    /*wp_multisite_nav_menu( $args );*/ 

    restore_current_blog(); 

}
```

I was expecting the menu to be placed in the 'Primary Navigation Menu' location.

What have I missed?

Any clarity is appreciated.

Comment: the call of `wp_nav_menu` renders directly the menu. in which hook do you use this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I didn't enter the correct hook. Here is the code that works for a genesis framework site.

```
add_action('genesis_after_header', 'primary_library_menu_switch');
    function primary_library_menu_switch() {
        global $blog_id;
        if ( ! is_multisite() || 2 == $blog_id ) {
        switch_to_blog( 1 );

        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 2,
            'fallback_cb'       => false,
            'menu_class'        => 'genesis-nav-menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary'
        ) );

        restore_current_blog(); 
    }
    }
```